# Charts drawn with %%chart command do not render

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have this query (a modified version of the query under the Line Chart section of the Datalab Tutorials notebook.)

```
`%%sql --module timeseries
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) AS timestamp, AVG(latency) AS latency,
FROM [cloud-datalab-samples:httplogs.logs_20140615]
WHERE endpoint = 'Popular'
GROUP BY timestamp`
```

followed by this call to %%chart

`%%chart bars --fields timestamp,latency --data timeseries`

but this doesn't seem to draw the required bar chart, even though I do not receive any error message. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be '--field', not '--fields', and there is no '--data'. So try:

```
%chart bars --field timestamp,latency timeseries
```

When I used your version, I did get an error message about 'too many data arguments', because the line parser tried to parse both '--data' and 'timeseries' as the positional data argument.