# %%chart line graph in Datalab based on Bigquery data not rendering

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am running a query against our GAP data in Bigquery and I want to generate a chart from it.

```
%%sql --module mobileGraph02
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY((visitStartTime+36000)*1000000),'%Y/%m/%d') AS dateDate,
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullVisitorId) AS sessions
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([99949271.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2016-02-21'), 
TIMESTAMP('2016-02-25')) 
GROUP BY dateDate
ORDER BY dateDate
```

I attempted to create a graph from this based on one of the examples in the 'Interactive Charts with Google Charting APIs' file.

```
%%chart line --fields dateDate,sessions --data mobileGraph02
```

And this version:

```
%%chart line -f dateDate,sessions -d mobileGraph02
```

The help document in the UI is returning the following:

```
%%chart line -h
usage: %%chart line [-h] [-f FIELDS] -d DATA

optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-f FIELDS, --fields FIELDS
                      The field(s) to include in the chart
-d DATA, --data DATA  The name of the variable referencing the Table or
                    Query to chart
```

I found that the chart itself was not rendering and there was no error message as per this post:
[Charts drawn with %%chart command do not render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259662/charts-drawn-with-chart-command-do-not-render)

Answer (score 0):

Datalab doesn't do much validation of the data before passing it to the charting library (that might change one day if https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/pull/676 gets merged). Errors might have been reported in the browser console, as a result, as the chart library is Javascript code.

Comment: What exactly resolved it? It turned out I was wrong about the string type; I tried charting this:

    data = [
      {'date': '2016/01/01', 'count': 10},
      {'date': '2016/01/02', 'count': 15},
      {'date': '2016/01/03', 'count': 12}  
    ]

and it worked fine.