# In datalab, Is it possible to pass data into a chart from python?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Trying to figure out if it is possible to reference python data as a source for creating a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
data = [
        {'date': '2016/01/01', 'count': 10}, 
        {'date': '2016/01/02', 'count': 15}, 
        {'date': '2016/01/03', 'count': 12} 
       ]
%chart pie -d data
```

As mentioned in the following post, check the browser console for additional detail regarding errors:

[%%chart line graph in Datalab based on Bigquery data not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693430/chart-line-graph-in-datalab-based-on-bigquery-data-not-rendering/35712444#35712444)

Comment: One comment to add, if you have a print statement after the "%chart ..." line, then the chart will not display.